# Tasks and how to use them properly C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I am currently using tasks in some projects, and I was wondering how can I actually run a parallel code multiple times with the same method.
Here is my code:

```
Task CPU1 = new Task(CPU1_DoWork);
Task CPU2 = new Task(CPU2_DoWork);

// And i wanted to execute the CPU1 Task multiple time here is how i used it:
while (Timer_General.IsRunning == true)
{
    if (CPU1.Status != TaskStatus.Running)
    {
        CPU1.Start(); 
    }
    if (CPU2.Status != TaskStatus.Running)
    {
        CPU2.Start(); 
    }
}

// Other Blabla
```

Why is he running `CPU1_DoWork` only once? Thanks for your help guys! :)

I added the CPU2 sequence because if we await the first, the second will not get called :/ So this poses a problem. Is there any other way to make my Tasks run multiple time at the same time?

Comment: the whole point behind tasks is to `await` on them and forget about them until they are finished

Comment: Excuse my ignorance if I'm way off but could threads be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Task` cannot be re-used. For each one you want to use you'll need to create a new instance. Instead of using the `Task`, you should use the built in factory method `Task.Run` which will return a hot task for you:

```
public async Task FooAsync()
{
    while (Timer_General.IsRunning)
    {
        await Task.Run(CPU1_DoWork);
    }
}
```

As you're checking for `Task.IsRunning`, I'm assuming you want to asynchronously wait for each task to complete, hence I added the `await` keyword.

**Edit:**

Since you added a second task and want them botg to run in parallel, you can use `Task.WhenAll`:

```
public async Task FooAsync()
{
    while (Timer_General.IsRunning)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(Task.Run(CPU1_DoWork), 
                           Task.Run(CPU2_Work));
    }
}
```